# RazorPDF and Chinese character

Tags: character-encoding, razorpdf

I use Razor-PDF to create PDF. 
like  the following article:

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2013/06/Creating-PDF-with-ASP-Net-MVC-and-RazorPDF.html

But I have a problem. the data consists of Chinese characters,but Chinese characters  don't appear in PDF file I created. can anyone help me how to do this? thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same issue with Hebrew. Have you found a solution for it ?